# Copy site to another domain - XML SiteMap wrong and Theme Settings not the same

Tags: backups

I copied my productive site from www.mydomain.com to a testsite www.mytestsite.com on the same server. I did it this way:
On productive server:

- Set productive site to offline
- Disabled Clean URL
- Emptied Cache
- created backup with the "backup and migrate" tool. All tables are backuped exept all cache-table and watchdog
- Copy *all* files

On target test server:

- Create new empty DB
- Import SQL script via MySQLAdmin from provider
- Copy all files
- change settings.php
- Login as Admin, set online, enable clean url, empty cache

Now I should have an identical site. But I have two differences (maybe more, which I cannot see):

1. XML Sitemap: Takes still the old domain name ("www.mydomain.com"). I can delete it and rebuild, no change. Why? This means that somewhere in a file the domain name must be written
2. The colors of hyperlinks are blue instead green as in the original site. When I go to "Theme settings" and simply press "save", then all is ok. Also here: Why is there wrong information about theme settings? Is this not saved in the DB?

Any help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to admin/config/search/xmlsitemap/settings and set the correct domain. If that does not work look at your variable table in database and make sure xmlsitemap_base_url is correct.
2. Make sure your folder permissions are correct. If you have caching enabled and some themes need to write temp files inside sites/default/files so make sure permissions are correct and that Drupal can write there.

If that does not work can you inspect where the styles are coming from using Firebug and also post what theme you are using and I can update my answer.

Comment: thanks for your help.  sitemap worked, I did not see the advanced settings. about folder permissions: I will test it and migrate site again. just a question: why can it be because of permissions? when I went to theme settings and pressed "save" all was ok. this seems like permissions are ok

Comment: Depending on theme some themes have to write files into sites/default/files folder depending on theme. If they are not able to save those settings it will show everything correctly but it will revert back. What theme are you using?